# ¿Cambiar el nombre de mi app generado desde Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Cuando genero mi app con el siguiente comando

```
flutter build apk --releasse
```

Me genera un apk con el nombre **app-release.apk**  por defecto.

Existe manera de cambiarlo? es decir, hacer el mismo comando pero que se genere con el nombre.

```
miApp.apk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para cambiar el nombre de la compilación, podes modificar el archivo app/build.gradle, ahí podes modificarlo para generar diferentes flavor de la app

```
android {
…
flavorDimensions "env"

productFlavors {
   ...
   flavor1 {
       dimension "env"
       applicationId "com.test.flavor"
       resValue "string", "app_name", "miapp"
       versionName "1.0.0"
       versionCode 1
   }
  }
}
```

al momento de compilar la app se debe agregar el parametro

> --flavor flavor1

esto hace que al querer compilar la app puedas modificar id de la app por si tienes varias versiones de la app o tienes que compilarla para diferentes clientes, ya que modificando el app id y el app_name puedes cambiar el identificador y el nombre de la app por el que corresponda